# JavaScript - select which variable to pass based on the value of another variable (without using an if)

Tags: javascript, variables

I would like to choose which variable to pass to a funciton based on the value of another variable, without using an IF or switch statement.

For example, if var1 = yellow, than pass variable yellow. If var1 = red, then pass variable red. But without using an IF...

Actual example: I have a bunch of variables declared that match the names that I expect to be returned by the evt.target.$name call below. I want to pass the variable that corresponds to the value of event.target.$name.

```
    var listener = function (evt) {
        toPass = evt.target.$name;
        myInfobubbles.addBubble("hello", toPass);
    }
```

I'm a JavaScript newbie so sorry if the answer is obvious.

Comment: Where are these variables defined?

Comment: I believe that eval is what you're after: `toPass = eval(evt.target.$name);`

Comment: @Shadow - not if it can be avoided.

Comment: @Nick - why not? What's wrong with eval?

Comment: @Shadow - Can't answer that in comments, not nearly enough room: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use bracket notation. It kind of depends where are your variables defined. If on `window` (the kind-of default):

```
var listener = function (evt) {
    toPass = evt.target.$name;
    myInfobubbles.addBubble("hello", window[toPass]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, the variables are defined with global scope in the same area. All the JS is currently sitting in the <head> area of my html document. Does "window" above refer to the scope of the variables?